# How to solve a geometric constraint problem

Tags: geometry, optimization

Here is what I know:

There is a rectangle with a short-side height of >= 36" but <= 42".

There is a square in the center of this rectangle with side length >= 25" but <= 28".

There is a line with a slope of the [golden ratio](https://jimwfonseca.medium.com/a-new-golden-triangle-e796bb3778e7) (can be imperceptibly approximate), $\phi$, that emanates from the top right of the rectangle and intersects the square at the bottom right and continues to intersect the bottom of the rectangle at the line's end point.

There is a line with a slope of the [golden ratio](https://jimwfonseca.medium.com/a-new-golden-triangle-e796bb3778e7) (can be imperceptibly approximate), $\phi$, that emanates from the bottom left of the rectangle and intersects the square at the top left and continues to intersect the top of the rectangle at the line's end point.

There is a line that emanates from the bottom left of the square to intersect at the line's end point at the bottom of the rectangle.

There is a line that emanates from the top right of the square to intersect at the line's end point at the top of the rectangle.

All lines are parallel.

The long length, bottom, of the rectangle is now $\mathscr{L}_b = \frac{x}{\phi} + x + \frac{36}{\phi}$ I believe. This length needs to be divided into $n$ equal portion segments in such a way that three conditions are met:

(1) **Perpendicular distance** between the parallel lines is less than or equal, but as close as possible, to 4".

(2) The division points intersect at the red dots (see below illustration)

(3) $\mathscr{L}_b$ needs to be <= 70"

[image]

What is $x$ and what is $n$?

I have created an approximation method of sorts to deduce that it needs to be 10 divisions, but there is so much variability here as I have described (i.e., "imperceptibly approximate", and the ranges) that there must be a better solution because as you can see the points to hit it perfectly:

[image]

Here above you can see I have four parallel lines as described above, and then having the perpendicular distance between the two outer lines divided into 10, 9, 8, etc. to see where those "division points" lay on the two interior parallel lines to get the division points I am looking for that are approximately 4" apart.

The reason, if curious, it needs to be less than 70" is that 2" will be added to this because it is a fence panel that is constrained to 72" to fit the space. Here is my first attempt up until the slope design had changed to this golden triangle scheme:

[image]

I have created a GeoGebra gadget here:

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kpwpuhcz